# Ambigious names for controller methods in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Image the following controller method:

```
public ActionResult ShipmentDetails(Order order)
{
    return View(new OrderViewModel { Order = order });
}
```

The incoming order parameter is filled from a custom model binder, that either creates a new order for this session and stores it in the session, or reuses an existing order from the current session. This order instace is now used to fill a shipment details form, where users can enter their address and so on.

When using `@using(Html.BeginForm())` in the view. I cannot use the same signature for the post method again (because this would result in ambigious method names) and I found me adding a dummy parameter just to make this work.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ShipmentDetails(Order order, object dummy)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return RedirectToAction("ShipmentDetails");

   return RedirectToAction("Initialize", order.PaymentProcessorTyped + "Checkout");
}
```

What are the best practices for this? Would you simply rename the method to something like `PostShipmentDetails()` and use one of the overloads of `BeginForm`? Or does the problem originate from the point, that the first method has the order parameter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the [ActionName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionnameattribute.aspx) attribuite:

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("ShipmentDetails")]
public ActionResult UpdateShipmentDetails(Order order) { ... }
```

or a more classic pattern:

```
public ActionResult ShipmentDetails(int orderId)
{
    var order = Repository.GetOrder(orderId);
    return View(new OrderViewModel { Order = order });
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ShipmentDetails(Order order)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return RedirectToAction("ShipmentDetails");

   return RedirectToAction("Initialize", order.PaymentProcessorTyped + "Checkout");
}
```

Comment: I didn't know about the ActionNameAttribute. Thanks for pointing it out.